# 2 Dimensional Pointers Storing Strings

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, 2d

I am having a little trouble coding in c. I am new to the language, I know java significantly better, and strings in c give me the biggest headache.

When I implement this code...

```
int num, n, i, j;
printf("How many students will you enter (min. 5)\n");
scanf("%d",&num);

char *fn = (char*)malloc(num * sizeof(char *));
char *ln = (char*)malloc(num * sizeof(char *));

for (n=0; n<num; n++)
{
    *(fn+n) = (char *)malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
    *(ln+n) = (char *)malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
}

printf("Enter students (firstName lastName score)\n");
for(i=0; i<num; i++)
{
    scanf("%s %s", &fn[i], &ln[i]);
}
for (i=0; i<num; i++)
{
    printf("%s %s\n", &fn[i], &ln[i]);
}
printf("You did it!");
```

it prints the first letter of each first and last name, then the entire name of the last person I enter.
For example,

```
Jane Doe
Greg Smith
```

as the user input would output

```
JGreg DSmith
Greg Smith
```

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: [Dont cast return of malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/5339899)

Comment: What is a "2 dimensional pointer"? There is nothing like that in C.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
char **fn = (char*)malloc(num * sizeof(char *));
char **ln = (char*)malloc(num * sizeof(char *));
```

at the time of declaration

```
char *fn = (char*)malloc(num * sizeof(char *));
char *ln = (char*)malloc(num * sizeof(char *));
```

char *fn; declares a pointer to character, which can hold a string, but not a array string.

check it out.